# Does any scripture other than Mahabharatha has the story of Savitri and Satyavan?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, savitri

Markandeya tells the story of Savitri and Satyavan to Yudhishthira in Mahabharatha. It is such a great story in which a woman named Savitri brings the kingdom and vision to her father-in-law, life to her husband, and sons to her father through rituals. It seems to be a more powerful story than others. It starts from [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03291.htm) and ends [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03297.htm) in Pativrata-mahatmya Parva of [Vana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/index.htm).

The phalasruthi for listening to the story is as follows

> The man that listeneth with reverence to the excellent story of
> Savitri, attaineth to happiness, and success in everything, and never
> meeteth with misery.

Although Mahabharatha's story of Nala and Damayanti is popular, many other scriptures contain the story. Is it the case with the story of Savitri and Satyavan also? I want to know **whether the story of Savitri and Satyavan is present in any other scriptures**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Devi Bhagavata Purana also has the story.

> The chaste Sâvitrî, too, followed him. Unfortunately Satyavâna fell
> down from a tree and died. Yama, the God of Death, saw his soul as a
> Purusa of the size of one’s thumb and took it and went away. The
> chaste Sâvitrî began to follow Him. The high souled Yama, the Foremost
> of the Sadhus, seeing Sâvitrî following Him, addressed her sweetly :--
> O Sâvitrî! Whither are you going in your this mortal coil? If you like
> to follow after all, then quit your this body.

> Here ends the Twenty-seventh Chapter of the Ninth Book on the birth,
> etc., of Sâvitrî in S’rî Mad Devî Bhâgavatam of 18,000 verses by
> Maharsi Veda Vyâsa.

> *On the story of Sâvitrî*
>
> 1-4. Nârâyana said :-- O Nârada! Hearing the words of Yama, the chaste
> intelligent Sâvitrî, replied with great devotion :-- “O Dharmarâjan!
> What is Karma? Why and how is its origin? What is the cause of Karma?
> Who is the embodied soul (bound by Karma)? What is this body? And who
> is it that does Karma? What is Jñâna? What is Buddhi? What is this
> Prâna of this embodied Jîva? What are the Indriyas? And what are their
> characteristics? And what are the Devatâs thereof? Who is it that
> enjoys and who is it that makes one enjoy? What is this enjoyment
> (Bhoga)? And what is the means of escape from it? And what is the
> nature of that State when one escapes from enjoyment? What is the
> nature of Jîvatmâ? And what of Paramâtmâ? O Deva! Speak all these in
> detail to me.”

Details of interactions between Savitri and Lord Yama are found spread in various chapters.

> Chapter XXX
> *On the conversation between Sâvitrî and Yama and on the fruition of Karmas*
>
> 1. Sâvitrî said :-- “O Dharmarâjan! Kindly tell me in detail about those works that lead the meritorious persons to the Heavens and
>    various other spheres
>
> The chaste woman having husband and sons who worships the World Mother
> Mûla Prakriti, whether in Yantra, or in Mantra or in image, enjoys all
> pleasures in this world; and, in the end, goes to the Devîloka or Mani
> Dvîpa. O Child! The worshipper Sâdhaka (one who is in one’s way to
> success) must worship all the manifestations of the Devî, day and
> night. At all times one must worship the omnipresent Durgâ, the
> Highest Îsvarî. There is no other way to attain blessedness than this.
> Thus saying, Dharmarâja went to His own abode. Sâvitrî, too, with her
> husband Satyavân went to her home. Both Sâvitrî and Satyavân, when
> they reached home, narrated all their stories to their friends and
> acquaintances. In time, by the blessing of Yama, Sâvitrî’s father got
> sons and father-in-law recovered his eye-sight and kingdom and Sâvitrî
> Herself got sons.

Many chapters of the 9th Book of the Purana have the story of Savitri and her interactions with Yamaraja.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is at least mentioned in four major Puranas, and one Upa-purana.

#### 1. In the Skanda Purana [7.1.166.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626954.html) it is referenced.

> Yama said:
>
> 57. I am Yama, who controls and restrains, the terror of all the worlds.
> 58. This husband of yours has come to the end of the span of his life. Yet, O chaste lady, in your presence, he cannot be led away by my
>     servants. Hence I have come personally.
> 59. After saying thus, Yama extracted forcibly the thumbsized inner soul from the body of Satyavrata (Satyavān) by means of his noose.
> 60. Then he began to proceed along the path resorted to by Pitṛs. The beautiful lady Sāvitrī too closely followed him.
>
> - 61-62. Yama spoke to her who was never tired, thanks to the power of
>   her fidelity to her husband. “O Sāvitrī, go back you have traversed
>   here for a Muhūrta. O lady of large eyes, this pathway cannot be
>   traversed by anyone.”
>
> Sāvitrī said:
>
> 63. I have no fatigue, I am not tired. Following my husband is never tiresome especially in the presence of an exalted person (like you).
> 64. Good people are the only resort unto good people, none else. Husband is the permanent resort unto women. The Veda is the sole
>     resort unto all the castes and stages of life and preceptor is the
>     ultimate resort unto disciples.
> 65. There is a place of rest and refuge on the earth for all living beings. But excepting the husband alone, there is no place of resort
>     unto women.
> 66. The son of the Sun-god (Yama) was pleased with these and such other equally sweet words couched in righteousness. He spoke to
>     Sāvitrī:
>
> ....
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare.

---

#### 2. The story is also referenced in the Matsya Purana - Chapter 208.

- Can be accessed in English [from here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45858/page/n219/mode/2up) & (Hindi + Sanksrit) Gita Press version [from here](https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n853/mode/2up?view=theater).

---

#### 3. Brahmavaivarta Puran.

- Also mentioned in the Brahmavaivarta Purana - Chapter 24, Prakriti Khanda.
  (Sanskrit Text + English) translation may be accessed [from here](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/n325/mode/2up) & the Gita Press only Hindi version [from here (page 206)](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n205/mode/2up).

---

#### 4. Vishnudharmottara Purana:

- It is also mentioned in Chapters 36 to 41, Part 2 of the Vishnudharmottara Upa-purana. However, no free English Translations are available online. One may access the only Sanskrit Text of the same from the Hinduism's Wikisource website: [viṣṇudharmottarapurāṇam/ khaṇḍaḥ 2/adhyāyāḥ 036-040](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/_%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AC-%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AA%E0%A5%A6)

---

### To Conclude -

- Besides Mahabharata, and other Puranas, the story of Satyavan-Savitri finds mentioned in:

  - Skanda Purana,
  - Matsya Purana, and
  - Brahmavaivarta Purana,
  - Vishnudharmottara Purana, and
  - Devi Bhagavatam, *(already answered on [this thread](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51338/17833))*